# Trying to 'replicate' shared_ptr upcasting behaviour cause an infinite recursion on copy constructor (that lead to a segfault)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am trying to replicate the shared_ptr behaviour to better understand template metaprogramming and type_traits in c++17.
Specifically, I want to replicate the upcasting behaviour, that is, the chance of assign/copy-create `shared_ptr< Derived >` to `shared_ptr< Base >` without any explicit cast.

The type checking is working, but I get a segfault for an infinite loop in copy-constructor, when trying to copy or assign the derived object.

Generic template-class

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Generic {
    public:
        template <typename DerivedT>
        using Assignable = typename std::enable_if<std::is_assignable<T, DerivedT>::value, Generic<T> &>::type;

        Generic() : _ptr(nullptr) {}


        Generic(T *ptr) : _ptr{ptr} {};

        Generic(Generic && cptr) :
                _ptr(std::move(cptr._ptr))
        {}

        Generic(const Generic & cptr) :
                _ptr{cptr._ptr}
        {}

        template <typename DerivedT, typename = Assignable<DerivedT>>
        Generic(const Generic<DerivedT> &cptr) 
            : Generic(static_cast<const Generic &>(cptr)._ptr)
        {}

        ~Generic() = default;

        Generic & operator=(Generic && cptr) = default;

        Generic & operator=(const Generic & cptr) {
            _ptr = cptr._ptr;
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename DerivedT>
        Assignable<DerivedT> operator=(const Generic<DerivedT> &cptr) {
            _ptr = static_cast<const Generic &>(cptr)._ptr;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        T* _ptr;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Generic.hpp"

struct Base {
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

int main() {
    Generic<Derived> derived = Generic<Derived>();
    Generic<Base> base(derived);
    //Generic<Base> base = derived;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue can be reduced to:

```
template <typename T>
class Generic {
    public:
        Generic() = default;

        Generic(T *ptr) : _ptr{ptr} {};

        template <typename Derived>
        Generic(const Generic<Derived> &cptr) :
          Generic(static_cast<const Generic &>(cptr)._ptr)
        {}

    private:
        T* _ptr = nullptr;
};

struct Base {
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

int main() {
    Generic<Derived> derived = Generic<Derived>();
    Generic<Base> base(derived);
}
```

The problem is that with `static_cast<const Generic &>(cptr)` you are implicitly creating an instance of `Generic<T>` form `Generic<Derived>`, thus recursivelly calling the constructor *ad infinitum*.

A possible fix is:

```
template <typename T>
class Generic {
    public:
        Generic() = default;

        Generic(T *ptr) : _ptr{ptr} {};

        template <typename Derived>
        Generic(const Generic<Derived> &cptr) :
          Generic(cptr._ptr)
        {}

    private:
        T* _ptr = nullptr;

    template <typename U>
    friend class Generic;
};

struct Base {
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

int main() {
    Generic<Derived> derived = Generic<Derived>();
    Generic<Base> base(derived);
}
```